# Is there a System enum in .Net for CSS Media Types?

Tags: .net, css, enums

I was wondering if there is an enum inside .NET that contains all the different media types that you can use in css?

Something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// List of available media types for css (comments from http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)
/// </summary>
public enum CssMediaType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for all media type devices
    /// </summary>
    all,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for speech and sound synthesizers
    /// </summary>
    aural,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for braille tactile feedback devices
    /// </summary>
    braille,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for paged braille printers
    /// </summary>
    embossed,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for small or handheld devices
    /// </summary>
    handheld,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for printers
    /// </summary>
    print,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for projected presentations, like slides
    /// </summary>
    projection,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for computer screens
    /// </summary>
    screen,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for media using a fixed-pitch character grid, like teletypes and terminals
    /// </summary>
    tty,
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for television-type devices
    /// </summary>
    tv
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never come across one ... but it looks like you've given it a heck of a go already :-)